# how to catch voice input when user speaks

Tags: android, voice

How to catch the voice input when user start speaking, as like talking tom application.
Can any one help me ?
i want to start the voice record when the user  start speaking  it must stop when user stop talking, as like how the talking tom application works.Can any one help ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use some Voice Activity Detection [(VAD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) algorithms. This signal processing stuff is usually written in C so you also have to learn something about using [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: You can check following SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367214/any-simple-vad-implementation